# Create Spotify playlist and add songs to it. Android

Tags: android, spotify, playlist

I'm working on an Android application and wonder, if there is a way to create and modify Spotify playlists by Intent.

I know it's possible to start songs by Intent, but I don't know when the song is finish, so my application cannot just start new songs when finished.

I've read about the Spotify Playlist API and that it should be possible by HTTP request in the  near future, but does anyone knows, when it is released?

Thanks in advance

Martin

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate Spotify directly in your application.

They just released [Spotify Library](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/#documentation) for android :)